# Cordova local notifications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have downloaded the example zip [from here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/example) and when I run the `cordova build android` command it throws me the following error:

```
 * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    Error: Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,"C:\Users\Sylvan\Desktop\cordova-plugin-local-notifications-example\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuild
    Debug -b C:\Users\Sylvan\Desktop\cordova-plugin-local-notifications-example\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedN
    dk=true"
```

Cordova -v: 6.4.0

These are my cordova platform versions:

Installed platforms:
android 5.1.1
ios 4.1.1
windows 4.2.0

And Iam also wondering if its possible to push local notifications to smartwatch as well? So when I recieve an local push notifications it also shows up on my watch?

Comment: request you to checkout the basic working sample of local notification Cordova app in the following link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Local_Notification

Answer (score -3):

Looks like an issue with your Java installation.

You should check to see if your Environment Variable is set correctly and is pointing to your JDK

Comment: The answer is that it's an issue with his Java installation. I can't ascertain what the issue is exactly, but the reason he is getting that issue is that it's an issue when the build is calling javac. 

So is everything a comment until there is a step by step response? The secondary question is to help more and try and resolve the issue (at which point I would edit my answer to reflect - Have edited the answer to make it clearer

Comment: Thanks for the response. Usually what you should do if you are not sure what the problem is, is post a comment asking for clarification or a possible answer. If you are correct, then post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I know what the problem is, it's just that to resolve the issue it could be a number of things. The issue is that his Java Environment on his machine isn't setup correctly. But there could be many reasons as to why that is though.

Comment: @AndrewBerry How do I check if my Environment Variable is set correctly? I thought all ready it had something to do with that so I update my java.. but no result

Comment: Control Panel -> System -> Advanced then on the advanced tab there will be an Environment Variables tab. or if you run a cmd window type java -version and see if it gives an error or not

Comment: @AndrewBerry `java -version

java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`